# Downgrading node getting error "Invalid version"

Tags: node.js, npm, downgrade

I installed `n` using `npm install -g n -f`, and now when I run `n 9` or `n 8` or `n 10` I always get the error:

```
$ n 9

  installing : node-v9.11.2

  Error: invalid version '9.11.2'
```

I don't understand why. These are valid versions.

When I run `node -v` I get:

```
v12.7.0
```

Any ideas why I might be getting this issue? It's really frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install any version of the node you want to use the following command to use the `n` module

`n <version> to install a version of node. Example:`

```
n 4.9.1 or

n 9.11.2 or

n 10 or

n latest or

n v8.11.3
```

After each installation, you will see a list of all the nodes available in the system with the `n` command prompt.

Finally, if the version of the node you want is available in the list provided, you can select and execute it with the ‍‍‍`$ n 9` command.